# Problems with peer dependencies while installing AngularMaterial

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, npm-install

I'm trying to install Angular Material on my project with npm and i'm kinda newb using this.

I've tried to use: `ng add @angular/material` ,but installs only @7.0.0 version and i need some of the new components. So, i've used: `ng add @angular/material@15.2.0` and some errors appeared on my console.

Log file:

```
# npm resolution error report

2023-02-23T15:15:23.428Z

While resolving: onu-visualization@0.0.0
Found: @angular/animations@14.2.12
node_modules/@angular/animations
  @angular/animations@"^14.2.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/animations@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/material@15.2.0
node_modules/@angular/material
  @angular/material@"15.2.0" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular/animations",
    "version": "14.2.12",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "onu-visualization",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "path": "D:\\ONU-Visualization\\Onu_visualization"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/animations",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "@angular/animations",
        "spec": "^14.2.0",
        "from": {
          "location": "D:\\ONU-Visualization\\Onu_visualization"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "@angular/animations",
    "spec": "^14.2.0",
    "from": {
      "location": "D:\\ONU-Visualization\\Onu_visualization"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@angular/animations",
    "spec": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@angular/material",
      "version": "15.2.0",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "onu-visualization",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "path": "D:\\ONU-Visualization\\Onu_visualization"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "@angular/material",
          "spec": "15.2.0",
          "from": {
            "location": "D:\\ONU-Visualization\\Onu_visualization"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

What am i doing wrong? And how can i install angular material to my application?

Comment: Use the force flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installed onu-visualization package is only supported with the @angular/animations package v14.2. The @angular/material@15.2.0 which you want to install comes with (depends on) @angular/animations v15+. Maybe look if there is a newer version of the onu-visualization package that supports the latest @angular/animations package. You can also install angular material with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag that installs the package and ignores potential unsupported version. But be careful with this, because it could break your application.

This link might be helpful as it explains the concept of peer-deps, which is the reason for your problem: https://indepth.dev/posts/1187/npm-peer-dependencies